# Web-scraping: No matching CSS slector

Tags: html, css, r, web-scraping, rvest

I just got into web scraping and I'm trying to scrape the data from this web page : https://www.warsofninja.eu/index.php

More precisely I'm trying to get one of the tables. The problem is, the data in that table are not structured in a way that suits my web scraping knowledge right now, so I need your help. I've tried with rvest package from **R**, but I finally chose the UIpath studio solution, which seemed to be a quicker way to reach my objective. Here's a screenshot of the code of that page, with the element of interest highlighted :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXIhx.png)

I can't select The text "à pillé" on it's own, and make it a variable or a column in the output table that I want. What's the trick here? How am I supposed to do that ? I looked all over the web for an answer and didn't find anything... I hope my question is understandable.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, add your attempts and your code, to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `vignette("selectorgadget")` from the `rvest` package. This is a good start. You can than get for example the `Top 10 Village` table with this code:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
#> Lade nötiges Paket: xml2

url <- "https://www.warsofninja.eu/index.php"
top_10_village <- read_html(url)  %>%
  html_nodes(".col:nth-child(1) td") %>%
  html_text()

tibble(`#`       = 1:10,
       Village   = top_10_village[seq(1, length(top_10_village), 2)],
       Habitants = top_10_village[seq(2, length(top_10_village), 2)])
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>      `#` Village       Habitants
#>    <int> <chr>         <chr>    
#>  1     1 Number 1      455      
#>  2     2 Beaumanoir    448      
#>  3     3 L'Astra       446      
#>  4     4 Yolo Land     438      
#>  5     5 Sexonthebeach 430      
#>  6     6 -.-           429      
#>  7     7 Konoha-       427      
#>  8     8 yuei          410      
#>  9     9 Memen         409      
#> 10    10 Moulin Huon   408
```

<sup>Created on 2018-09-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>